Is it possible to use reflection to compare two arrays with the same element types?
My class looks something like this:
public class Test
{
    public A[] ArrayA { get;set; }
}

public class A
{
    public string P1 { get;set; }
    public int P2 { get;set; }
}

Suppose I have two objects of Test class. I want to use reflection to compare the two, assuming that the array length of both ArrayA properties are the same in both objects.
For example:
Test a = new Test();
Test b = new Test();

// fill them with some info.

var props = typeof(Test).GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var arrayA = prop.GetValue(a);
    var arrayB = prop.GetValue(b);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.Lenght; i++)
    {
        var item1 = arrayA.GetValue(i);
        var item2 = arrayB.GetValue(i);
    
        // Do Comparison of item1 and item2
    }
}

So here's where I run into a problem. item1 and item2 are both of type object. I can't seem to get the original type from it. I can get the Type from the array, how do I use that to get the properties I want in item1 and item2? I want to use reflection to grab the property information of item1 and item2 in order to make the comparison. Is this doable?
FYI. I'm not interested in any other solutions outside of using reflection. I already how to do those.

If you want to check if two instances of "something" are effectively identical, same # of elements and same element order, then a simple check would be to serialize both to JSON and compare. JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a) == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b). Boxing objects without explicitly having a plan for their unboxing and then expecting to compare them should be avoidable & discouraged. Worst case, unbox the instances back to the expected type and handle the exception rather than defaulting to an expensive reflection-based solution.

Enumerable.SequenceEqual is your friend, no reflection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-9.0

I don't understand why you have to go the reflection route. Maybe I'm missing some information. But if you really do need to use reflection, just use object.Equals(item1, item2) and then override the Equals method in A to check for equality.

Because my classes has a lot of properties and each of those classes has a bunch of properties. Yes I can spend the time to do it one by one, but I'm trying to be lazy and save some time. Can we just stay on topic here? I'm not looking for other ways to do this except through reflection.

Type t = obj.GetType(); PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();

@Ilian You don't really even need to override Equals All you need to do is use a record and compiler will generate the Equals for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality

The problem you're having is exactly because you're insisting on using reflection.

While it is possible to do in reflection it will be slow, and you'll find yourself battling all kinds of edge cases when your object(s) start to get complicated. But for your simple example which has an array and an objects with simple string/int properties the following works how (I think) you expected.
public static bool AreEqual(object a, object b)
{
    var props = a.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if(prop.PropertyType.IsArray)
        {
            var arrayA = (Array)prop.GetValue(a);
            var arrayB = (Array)prop.GetValue(b);
            if(!AreArraysEqual(arrayA, arrayB))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!prop.GetValue(a).Equals(prop.GetValue(b)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static bool AreArraysEqual(Array a, Array b)
{
    for(var i=0;i<a.Length;i++)
    {
        if(!AreEqual(a.GetValue(i),b.GetValue(i)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

This can then be tested as follows:
Test a = new Test(){ ArrayA = new[]{ new A{P1 = "Foo", P2=1},new A{P1 = "Bar", P2=2}} };
Test b = new Test(){ ArrayA = new[]{ new A{P1 = "Foo", P2=1},new A{P1 = "Bar", P2=2}} };
Test c = new Test(){ ArrayA = new[]{ new A{P1 = "Foo", P2=2},new A{P1 = "Bar", P2=2}} };
Console.WriteLine(AreEqual(a,b)); // true
Console.WriteLine(AreEqual(a,c)); // false

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FN8ZLu

I'm not really concerned with performance, i was just using to test some samples of data that I was working with. However your AreEqual does work, when you use the array.GetValue(int index) to retreive the object. Once you get the object it's only typed as an object. You actually cannot get the properties for that object. I've already had used code just like yours, but I was getting nothing until I debugged and found that it couldn't get the properties through reflection after the Array.GetValue call. Seems like it stripped out all the type information and is only an object type.

I guess mine's slightly different. I was using a generic type something like AreArraysEqual(T[] a, T[] b). I'm going to see if yours makes any difference.

ok looks like it was my mistake. I used the generic type and used typeof(T) instead of typeof for the passed in array. So it was doing a typeof(object) which remains an object.

Reflection is a very cool technology, but it's extremely slow at runtime so it's better not to use it. It's being slowly replaced by compiler code generation.
I used the sharplab.io to show what exactly happens when you change a single word in your class definition. If you use a record instead of a class the compiler will do all the heavy lifting for you.
public record A
{
    public string P1 { get;set; }
    public int P2 { get;set; }
}

The actual class that gets compiled looks like this:
[NullableContext(1)]
[Nullable(0)]
public class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private string <P1>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private int <P2>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    protected virtual Type EqualityContract
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return typeof(A);
        }
    }

    public string P1
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <P1>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <P1>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public int P2
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <P2>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <P2>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("A");
        stringBuilder.Append(" { ");
        if (PrintMembers(stringBuilder))
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(' ');
        }
        stringBuilder.Append('}');
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    protected virtual bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack();
        builder.Append("P1 = ");
        builder.Append((object)P1);
        builder.Append(", P2 = ");
        builder.Append(P2.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    [NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public static bool operator !=(A left, A right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    [NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public static bool operator ==(A left, A right)
    {
        if ((object)left != right)
        {
            if ((object)left != null)
            {
                return left.Equals(right);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<Type>.Default.GetHashCode(EqualityContract) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(<P1>k__BackingField)) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(<P2>k__BackingField);
    }

    [NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as A);
    }

    [NullableContext(2)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual bool Equals(A other)
    {
        if ((object)this != other)
        {
            if ((object)other != null && EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract && EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(<P1>k__BackingField, other.<P1>k__BackingField))
            {
                return EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(<P2>k__BackingField, other.<P2>k__BackingField);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual A <Clone>$()
    {
        return new A(this);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    protected A(A original)
    {
        <P1>k__BackingField = original.<P1>k__BackingField;
        <P2>k__BackingField = original.<P2>k__BackingField;
    }

    public A()
    {
    }
}

As you see every method that needs to be overwritten to support value equality has been written by the compiler. No need to do it manually. Add as many properties as you like, the compiler will generate code for all of them.
You can just use == to compare two instances and they will be equal if all their properties are equal.
[EDIT] Stole an example from @Jamiec
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test: IEquatable<Test>
{
    public A[] ArrayA { get;set; }

    public override bool Equals(object test) => true;

    public static bool operator ==(Test left, Test right) 
        => left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(Test left, Test right) 
        => !left.Equals(right);

    public bool Equals(Test test) 
        => ArrayA.SequenceEqual(test.ArrayA);

    public override int GetHashCode() 
        => ArrayA != null ? HashCode.Combine(ArrayA.Select(a => a.GetHashCode()).ToArray()) : 0;
}

public record A
{
    public string P1 { get;set; }
    public int P2 { get;set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test a = new(){ ArrayA = new A[]{ new(){ P1 = "Foo", P2=1 },new(){ P1 = "Bar", P2=1 }} };
        Test b = new(){ ArrayA = new A[]{ new(){ P1 = "Foo", P2=1 },new(){ P1 = "Bar", P2=1 }} };
        Test c = new(){ ArrayA = new A[]{ new(){ P1 = "Foo", P2=1 },new(){ P1 = "Bar", P2=2 }} };
        
        Console.WriteLine(a == b); // True
        Console.WriteLine(a == c); // False
        
    }
}


That's interesting. It might come useful in the future, however I'm not necessarily intending to change my class to a record :). And it wouldn't work with a class that you have no control over.

I agree this could not be the solution for you. Record is a super simple implementation of the ValueObject pattern so it requires to be an architectural decision. Currently I even create my EFCore models as records so I can use a simple == to look if data already exists in the database.
